# CodeNarc - determine if a class is a Grails integration test

Tags: grails, codenarc

I'd like to write a custom CodeNarc rule that validates some aspects of Grails integration test classes.  e.g. Spock integration tests should extend IntegrationSpec; not Specification.

But to do this, I need to filter on integration tests while visiting the classes in the rule, and I don't know how to do that.

One idea was to look at the source file path to see if it's in `test/integration`, but I don't know if it's possible to get the source path of a file.?  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely limit rule application based on path (as well as class name). Take a look at the [configuring rules](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-configuring-rules.html) CodeNarc page.

In particular, you're probably looking for the `applyToClassNames` and `doNotApplyToClassNames` properties or the `applyToFileNames` and `doNotApplyToFileNames` properties, which should be available on any of the built-in Rules and any custom rules that extend the provided `AbstractRule` class.